# What's the difference between after-init-hook and emacs-startup-hook

Tags: hooks

Seems there are several hooks about actions on Emacs initialization. However I'm not sure what their differences are, and a brief Googling yields little information. Is it like `emacs-startup-hook` is executed instantly after Emacs is fired up, but it doesn't necessarily wait for initialization to finish?

Comment: As @glucas suggested, just *ask Emacs*. Google is there if you want other info/opinions about such things, but start with Emacs's own info/opinion about itself. And if you cannot find the info you are looking for, consider filing a doc bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See the [Startup Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary) section of the Emacs Lisp manual for a detailed description of the things that happen when you start Emacs.

The `emacs-startup-hook` runs later than the `after-init-hook`.

One key difference is that there may be command-line options processed after the `after-init-hook` and before the `emacs-startup-hook`. (Command-line options are handled in multiple phases, with some being processed right away and some after init files have been loaded.)