# Why after-init-hook is not invoked? (workaround is emacs-startup-hook)

Tags: hooks

**short story**: The theme just did not show up automatically at emacs start, when it is invoked by an after-init-hook. However, with emacs-startup-hook it worked as expected:

```lisp
(use-package heaven-and-hell
  ...
;;:hook (after-init . heaven-and-hell-init-hook) ;; does not work
  :hook (emacs-startup . heaven-and-hell-init-hook) ;; this one does
```

I run plain emacs (`emacs -l test.el -Q`) with a test script (modified from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39159/kill-initial-buffers))

**test.el**

```lisp
(defun buffer-hook-function ()
  (append-to-file (format "%s" (buffer-list)) nil  "log.txt")
  (append-to-file "\n" nil  "log.txt")
  )

(append-to-file "Running ...\n" nil  "log.txt")

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (append-to-file "emacs-startup-hook\n" nil  "log.txt")))
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (append-to-file "after-init-hook\n" nil  "log.txt")))
(add-hook 'before-init-hook (lambda () (append-to-file "before-init-hook\n" nil  "log.txt")))
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook (lambda () (append-to-file "window-setup-hook\n" nil  "log.txt")))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (append-to-file "emacs-startup-hook after window-setup-hook\n" nil  "log.txt")))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (append-to-file (format "after-init-time %.2fs (printed via emacs-startup-hook)\n" (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) after-init-time))) nil "log.txt")))
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'buffer-hook-function)
```

**log.txt**

```
Running ...
  (*scratch*  *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *Echo Area 0*  *Echo Area 1*)
  after-init-time 0.03s (printed via emacs-startup-hook)
  emacs-startup-hook after window-setup-hook
  emacs-startup-hook
  window-setup-hook
  (*scratch*  *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *Echo Area 0*  *Echo Area 1*)
```

So after-init-hook does not appear, but after-init-time seems to be set, [which seems to come from an after-init-hook](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/64684356595be58ec939939997d16bc8cf624825/lisp/startup.el#L287).

I still do not see why after-init-hook is not called. [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/whats-the-difference-between-after-init-hook-and-emacs-startup-hook) refers to the command-line processing part of after-init-hook, so I tried different configurations, terminals and (non-)window modes.

- Why after-init-hook is not called?
- Does this mean, other packages with init hooks can also fail?

Edit: Using emacs 26.2, Manjaro Linux 18.0.4 xfce

**Update**: after rewriting my theme and addressing an [issue](https://github.com/nashamri/spacemacs-theme/issues/149) in spacemacs-theme, `after-init` seems to work so far via `heaven-and-hell`. `emacs-startup` hook had other issues like additional syntax highlighting via `prog-mode-hook` did not work.

**Update 2**: The example **test.el** perhaps always fails. If you run without `-Q` it is invoked: `emacs -l test.el`:

```
Running ...
<snip>
  after-init-hook
  (*scratch*  *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *Echo Area 0*  *Echo Area 1*  *load*)
  Running ...
  (*scratch*  *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *Echo Area 0*  *Echo Area 1*)
  after-init-time 0.06s (printed via emacs-startup-hook)
  emacs-startup-hook after window-setup-hook
  emacs-startup-hook
  window-setup-hook
<snip>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why after-init-hook is not called?

It is called, but it's called before `test.el` gets a chance to modify it.  [(elisp) Startup Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html):

```
 17. It runs the normal hook `after-init-hook'.

 [...]

 21. It processes any command-line options that were not handled
     earlier.

 [...]

 25. It runs `emacs-startup-hook'.
```

"command-line options that werer not handled earlier" includes `-l test.el`.  So by the time you are adding to `after-init-hook` it is too late.

Comment: ok, I just guessed loading el-files must come earlier than after-init-hook processing (`5. It does some basic parsing of the command-line arguments.`?). Otherwise is there a way at all for loading custom init files via command line besides of the [hardcoded](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) options?

Comment: I can answer my comment: No. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html): `after-init-hook: This normal hook is run, once, just after loading all the init files (site-start.el, your init file, and default.el), before loading the terminal-specific library (if started on a text terminal) and processing the command-line action arguments.`